# How to solve yii2 execution time out error with multiple databases

Tags: php, oracle, yii2

I have setup two database connections in my application. One for mysql and the other for oracle db.
I have tested both connections individually by reading data from tables in each database and everything works fine. When generating a model using gii with the **db2** as the database connection id, I get a timeout error. I have increased the execution time of the script to 300 seconds and still get the execution timeout error. When using **db** with gii it works ok.

The db config in the db.php is as shown:

```
return [
    'mysql' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=' . DATABASE_SERVER . ';port=' . DATABASE_PORT. ';dbname=' . DATABASE_NAME,
        'username' => DB_USER,
        'password' => DB_PASS,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
    'oracle' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'oci:dbname=//dbserver:dbport/dbname;charset=UTF8',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password'
    ],
]
```

In my web.php I have this:

```
$db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php';

$config = [
// 

'components' => [
   //

  'db' => $db['mysql'],
  'db2' => $db['oracle'],

   //
]

//

]
```

Comment: You'll probably need to do some query tuning to identify and fix the slow Oracle SQL statement(s). Query tuning is a huge topic, but to get started, while the application is waiting, run this query to identify the slow query: `select sql_id, sql_text, gv$sql.* from gv$sql where users_executing >= 1;` Plug the SQL_ID into this statement to generate a SQL Monitor Report: `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('<SQL_ID value>') from dual;` Analyze the execution plan, or talk to a DBA, or post the results here. This process can take long time.

Answer (score 0):

try to increase connection timeout. in main-local.php

```
'db' => [
    'attributes' => [
        PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 10, // timeout value in seconds
    ]
]
```